# Changing data and style with <select> in Leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, geojson, select, popup

I'm loading a GeoJSON layer in Leaflet, and would like to be able to change the properties of each feature by using a  box in the feature's popup. When the feature's property changes, I'd like to change the style of the feature as well.

I'm sure this is possible- I've read several change style/property questions, and several javascript-in-popups questions, but just can't seem to get it right.

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/quu3ykp6/7/

Desired workflow is as follows: user clicks a feature, changes the  box in the popup, this calls a javascript function that changes the style and properties of the feature in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code you provide in your JSFiddle:

```js
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

  var popup = '<select name="select" onchange="restyleLayer(this.value)">'
  popup += '<option value="Nope" selected>None</option>'
  popup += '<option value="Democrat">Democrat</option>'
  popup += '<option value="Republican">Republican</option>'
  popup += '</select>'
  layer.bindPopup(popup);

}
```

=> JSFiddle does not like inline JavaScript. If you open your browser console and change a popup select, it will throw a message stating "restyleLayer is not defined".

Instead, you should create HTMLElements, fill the `<option>`'s `value` and `innerHTML`, append them to your `<select>`, and attach an event listener to that `<select>`:

```js
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

  var select = document.createElement('select'),
    option0 = document.createElement('option'),
    option1 = document.createElement('option'),
    option2 = document.createElement('option');

  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    restyleLayer(this.value, this.layer);
  });

  select.layer = layer;

  option0.value = 'Nope';
  option0.selected = true;
  option0.innerHTML = 'None';

  option1.value = 'Democrat';
  option1.innerHTML = 'Democrat';

  option2.value = 'Republican';
  option2.innerHTML = 'Republican';

  select.appendChild(option0);
  select.appendChild(option1);
  select.appendChild(option2);

  layer.bindPopup(select);

}
```

Then:

```js
function restyleLayer(party) {

  states_geojson.eachLayer(function(layer) {

    // update the actual layer to the property from the select
    layer.feature.properties.party = party;

    var myFillColor = getColor(party);

    layer.setStyle({
      fillColor: myFillColor
    });
  });
}
```

When you change the select value for one of your polygons, you apply the change to **each layer** of your `states_geojson` GeoJSON layer group. This is very probably not what you are trying to achieve, which is most probably to change the `party` only for the polygon with open popup. So you should pass the current layer as another argument of your `restyleLayer` function.

Furthermore:

```js
function getColor(party) {
  console.log(party)
  switch (party) {
    case 'Republican':
      return {
        color: "#ff0000"
      };
    case 'Democrat':
      return {
        color: "#0000ff"
      };
    case 'Nope':
      return {
        color: 'grey'
      };
  }
}
```

Your `getColor` function returns an object, not a simple color as string. Therefore:

```js
var myFillColor = getColor(party);

layer.setStyle({
  fillColor: myFillColor
});
```

…is incorrect, as it ends up with something like:

```js
layer.setStyle({
  fillColor: {
      color: "#0000ff"
  }
});
```

So instead you just need:

```js
layer.setStyle(myFillColor);
```

For example:

```js
function restyleLayer(party, layer) {

  layer.feature.properties.party = party;

  var myFillColor = getColor(party);

  layer.setStyle(myFillColor);
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/quu3ykp6/9/

Comment: thank you so much for your help-- definitely improves my understanding of javascript, html and leaflet. Thank you!